# Why is the offset variable not included in the design matrix?

Tags: statistics

Say we have response $X\beta$, where $X$ is the design matrix. We know that the offset variable has a coefficient equal to $1,$ so why do we not simply put $1$ into the $\beta$ vector and the corresponding offset values into $X$?

Where is the offset represented? Would the response be $X\beta+t$, where $t$ is the offset?

Comment: By "offset variable" do you mean a column of $X$ in which all entries are identical?

Comment: @MichaelHardy I mean a variable that appears in the right-hand side of the linear predictor with a known coefficient equal to 1. For example: $\mu_i= \beta_0+\beta_1 x_i+t_i$, where $t_i$ is the offset variable.

Comment: Are the values of $t_i$ part of the observable data?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes.

Comment: If you did put $1$ into the $\beta$ vector, you'd also add a corresponding column to the design matrix $X.$ Thus $$ X\beta = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & x_1 & t_1 \\  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 1 & x_n & t_n  \end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{c} \beta_0 \\ \beta_1 \\ 1 \end{array} \right]. $$

Comment: Whatever you do after that, you'd probably want not only to estimate $\beta$ but also to find t-statistics and F-statistics, so you might have to consider what the effect would be on the calculuation of those.

Comment: I wonder if this question would fare better at stats.stackexchange.com .